# How to handle post request in Laravel app from another app?

Tags: php, laravel

I expect in Laravel 5.2 app post request from other system, when I handle it I receive:

> TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 67:

Normally when I send post form I add in code {{ csrf_field() }}, but in this case request is from different app. So how to handle it without error?

Answer (score 2):

You can add the URIs that should be excluded from verification to the `$except` property in the `VerifyCsrfToken` middleware.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken as BaseVerifier;

class VerifyCsrfToken extends BaseVerifier
{
    /**
     * The URIs that should be excluded from CSRF verification.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $except = [
        'api/*',
    ];
}
```

[Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/csrf#csrf-excluding-uris)

Answer (score 1):

You can exclude URI, to which reuqest from another application is send, from CSRF protection. This is described in doc [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/csrf#csrf-excluding-uris)